# Highstock reverts to same color for columns

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart that is populated dynamically. The chart is based on [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update). One of the series is "column" series. When I call series.addPoint, the point object contains the color property, which is set to either red or green.

When there are just a few data points, the column colors are red or green, but when there is a lot of data, the colors of all bars switch to blue. Do you know how to prevent the color from switching to blue?

The other issue is the date in the tooltip shows Week of [Date] instead of just stating the Date. Not sure if the root cause of this issue is the same.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some sample code that replicates your problem or create a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is relted with fact that in Highstock, dataGrouping is enabled, so data is grouped and have "no knowledge" which color should be. So I advice to disable dataGrouping.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled